# How to print a square based on main parameters

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point, atoi

So I have this code. I am stuck on this trial where the parameter to main is ["2"].

```
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    void my_square(int x, int y) {
    
        if(x == 5 && y == 3){
            printf("o---o\n");
            printf("|   |\n");
            printf("o---o\n");
        }
        if(x == 5 && y == 1){
            printf("o---o\n");
        }
        if(x == 1 && y == 1){
            printf("o\n");
        }
        if(x == 1 && y == 5){
            printf("o\n");
            printf("|\n");
            printf("|\n");
            printf("|\n");
            printf("o\n");
        }
        if(x == 4 && y == 4){
            printf("o--o\n");
            printf("|  |\n");
            printf("|  |\n");
            printf("o--o\n");
        }
        if(x == 2 && y == 2){
            printf("oo\noo\n");
        } 
        if(x == 2 && y == 0){
            printf("");
        }
        
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
        if(atoi(argv[1]) && atoi(argv[2])){
            my_square(atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));
        } 
        if( atoi(argv[1]) && atoi(argv[2]) == '\n'){
            my_square(atoi(argv[1]), 0);
        }
    
        return  0;
    }
```

[Tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REa9F.png)
With input ["2"], Output should be an empty space. But I don't know how write the code to solve this. Any thoughts on how to do this ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi(argv[2]) == '\n'` is not the correct way to tell if the second argument was omitted and you need to provide a default value for it. If only one argument is supplied, `argv[2]` will be `NULL`, and you can't pass it to `atoi()`. Also, `'\n'` is equivalent to `10` -- why would you expect `atoi()` to return that number for a nonexistent value?

To tell how many arguments were supplied, check `argc`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        my_square(atoi(argv[1]), 0);
    } else if (argc > 2) {
        my_square(atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));
    } else {
        printf("Usage: %s x [y]\n", argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In `my_square()` if you want to print a line containing an empty space, use:

```
if (x == 2 && y == 0) {
    printf(" \n");
}
```

`printf("")` doesn't print anything at all.

You also should use `else if` in `my_square()`, since all the conditions are mutually exclusive. There's no point in checking all the remaining combinations once you've found a match.

Comment: That didn't work. I want to pass those to my_square(). Therefore shouldn't it  be my_square(atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2])); for the else-if you wrote above ?

Comment: `printf("");` doesn't print an empty space. It prints nothing.

Comment: Isn't that what I have in my `else if`?

Comment: If you want to print a line with an empty space, use `printf(" \n");`

Comment: Wait no it actually worked. I didn't see your code was meant to check the arguments supplied. I also had to call my_square in the else and pass in say (0,0) and write a condition in my_square() that implements those parameters. Thank you very much.

Comment: And I was a little tripped up about what ```printf("");```  was printing and didn't see your comments and yes your code is correct. I just had to call my_square in the else. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There's nothing in the original code that does `my_square(0, 0)` when no arguments are supplied.

Comment: Yes I added it.